# Centrar botón entre dos columnas IONIC 3

Tags: html, css, ionic

Tengo el siguiente codigo en Ionic 3

```
 <ion-grid>
    <ion-row text-center>
        <ion-col col-6>
            <h1>AR</h1>
            <h2>Title</h2>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col col-6>
            <h1>AR</h1>
            <h2>Title</h2>
        </ion-col>
        <button ion-fab color="primary"><ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon></button>
    </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

Y lo ue necesito es centrar el botón por encima de las dos columnas, como muestra la imagen en la parte inferior:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La clave esta en el correcto uso de las columnas y usar las posiciones del fab button gracias al contenedor ion-fab.

En ionic, si no se especifican los tamaños de las columnas, estas van a tomar espacios iguales para llenar la row. Entonces, metemos el `ion-fab` dentro una `ion-col` de tamaño 1 en el medio de las otras 2 columnas. Finalmente puedes acomodar la posicion del `ion-fab` con las directivas `center` y `middle`

```
<ion-grid>
  <ion-row text-center>
    <ion-col style="background-color: blue;">
      <h1>AR</h1>
      <h2>Title</h2>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col col-1>
      <ion-fab center middle>
        <button ion-fab color="primary">
          <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
        </button>
      </ion-fab>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col style="background-color: blue;">
      <h1>AR</h1>
      <h2>Title</h2>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

El resultado sería el que sigue:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Dejé un ejemplo en línea en el siguiente stackblitz (ver el home.html):

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-1ar82c

Comment: Quedó perfecto! Muchas gracias.